# CComPtr pass by reference

Tags: c++, atl, smart-pointers, winapi, xmllite

I have a situation where I need to pass a `CComPtr<IXmlReader>` to a function by reference. Does the called parameter takes the ownership from the callee parameter (or) the reference count is increased?

```
void foo( CComPtr<IXmlReader> & pReader )
{
  // There is no reassignment of the CComPtr.
  // Just call the IXmlReader methods.
}

CComPtr<IXmlReader> pReader;
foo( pReader );

// Is pReader still valid after the function return ?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reassignment, why is it a reference parameter?

Regardless, there is no change in the reference count. Yes, the CComPtr is still valid after returning.

Comment: Perhaps he means to pass by const reference for performance reasons.

Comment: If there is no need for reference counting (changing the value of the pointer) in the foo function, and you are worried about reference counting overhead, I would just make the parameter a simple pointer (non-CComPtr wrapped pointer).

Answer (score 0):

No reference counting affected by the call itself, it is only inner function manipulation with the pointer which might be adding or releasing number of references to the object.

> // Is pReader still valid after the function return ?

Yes, unless the function re-assigned the value, setting it to `NULL` or putting in there a new value.

Even if the argument in input-only, there is a programmer's bonus in passing arguments this way: (1) you are completely staying within domain of smart pointers and you don't need to worry a lot about proper reference counting (2) you have assertion failure on e.g. trying to `->` an uninitialized pointer (3) release build optimizations will/might be generating nearly as fast code as if you used raw pointer instead.